# What is the maximum number of reduce moves that can be taken by a bottom-up parser for a grammar with no epsilon and unit-production

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

What is the maximum number of reduce moves that can be taken by a bottom-up parser for a grammar with no epsilon and unit-production (i.e., of type $A \rightarrow \epsilon$ and $A \rightarrow a$) to parse a string with $n$ tokens?

1. $n/2$
2. $n-1$
3. $2n-1$
4. $2^n$

---

My attempt:

Let the grammar is:

$S→AB$

$A→aa |AB$

$B→bb |BA$

Let the string $w=aabb$ , string length is $4$ (say , $n$)

so, the required productions are : $S→AB$ ,$A→aa$ , $B→bb$ , number of production is $3 = n-1$

> > Can you explain it in a formal way, please?

This question([see-Q.no.-4](http://www.gate.iitb.ac.in/gate2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/CS-C.pdf)) is from competitive exam [GATE](http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/) , and answer key is given option $n-1$ ([see-q.no.-of-set-c](http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/2013answers/CS.pdf))

Comment: Can you edit the title so it gives some idea of what the problem is about?

Comment: @GerryMyerson , I edited

Comment: No, you didn't. I asked you to edit the **title** so it gives some idea of what the problem is about. "Better approach to solve this problem?" could be about *anything*.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I've edited title.

Comment: Welcome back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. However it does not prove that it is the maximum. It only says that there exist a grammar that use n-1 reduce move.

You should also prove that no grammar can use more.

Hint: Since there is no epsilon and unit production, what can you says on the number of letters when applying a reduce move?